# No HDD in boot order in BIOS in Asus x555LA

Tags: 12.04, boot, uefi, secure-boot

Today I bought a brand new ASUS X555LA laptop with Window 8 pre-installed. So I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 64bit using a USB flash drive. My first boot was USB (not UEFI) and I was successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

After a reboot the monitor shows `no device to boot`. So I went into the BIOS and I found out that there is no HDD in the boot order list. But I can see HDD information in the Advanced tab of the BIOS. To double check the HDD I booted using a LiveCD and found out that the HDD is still there. After that I enabled secure boot in the BIOS,restarted the system and ask what? DVDROM also gone from the Boot order. Factory reset of the BIOS didn't help. Now only the USB flash drive can boot

I am not a newbie and I am aware of UEFI/secure boot but this thing is new. I need your help guys.

Comment: It is "I", not "i"...  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question for future references.

## Problem:

My laptop comes with locked `UEFI` mode. So there is no option to disable `UEFI boot`. Still i can boot `usb flash` drive in non `UEFI` mode.

## Solution:

I have created a new partition of `200 MB`, format `fat32` and set mount point as `EFI boot`. Other options of installation process are same. Also `Ubuntu 12.04` unable to setup `UEFI` boot so I switch to `14.04`.